# Texturing models in Blender

Tags: texturing, uv, texture-painting

I a complete beginner in Blender. (I use 2.8 version of it). I used to work with cinema 4d years ago, so I have the idea about some basics of working with 3D. But as I see Blender is a lot more complicated and complex.

I found this model online and made used a Decimate modifier to reduce the size. Now I need to colorize it but for some reason I face this issue:

After unfolding UV and painting the model it paints the inside part of it.

[image: The example of blender model texture paint]

This happens when I zoom inside the model and paint it from the a side:

[image]

UPD.1
I figured out it has to do with Normals facing different directions, I recalculated them outside, it seemed to help a little but still it very edgy.
There are some lines between the polygons and some of normals keep facing the wrong direction.[image]

Answer (score 2):

I believe some of your face normals are flipped OR you have overlapping faces / really rough topology, OR you need to unwrap your model more cleanly without UV distortion and maybe even increase the UV texture resolution.

**To fix normals:** <kbd>Tab</kbd> for Edit Mode, then <kbd>A</kbd> to select all. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> to recalculate normals (untick "inside").

**Fix overlapping geometry:** a quick fix might be Re-Mesh modifier. Be sure to save an alternate version before flattening ("applying") a modifier because it is destructive.

**UV Unwrap quick fix:** Edit Mode, select all faces, <kbd>U</kbd> "Lightmap Pack" or "Smart UV Project". Make sure your UV image texture is a large enough resolution and that your UV islands have enough margins between to prevent overlap.

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer, I've tried to fix normal, but unfortunately many of them keep facing wrong direction. What about Re-Mesh, I need to keep it low poly and recognisable, after re-mesh it really looses the shape.

Comment: Have you tried to Set Origin>Origin to Geometry in Object mode? Do that, and THEN recalculate normals. See if that helps. Also, try Ctrl+A to apply Scale, Location, and Rotation. Then try recalculating normals.

Comment: Maybe try backface cull, view from inside the mesh, select only facing faces and recalculate those alone and flip them outwards?